# Setting HTTPOnly flag on cookie in varnish 4

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

We have cookies that are generated by an appliance in our infrastructure, we do not have access to the configuration of the appliance so cannot set the HTTPOnly flag on the cookies it generates directly.

We do have a varnish 4 cache in front of this appliance, is it possible to set the HTTPOnly flag on the cookie there? If so how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your backend only sets one `Set-Cookie` header per response, adding the `HttpOnly` flag to that header can be trivially done during the `vcl_deliver` subroutine. You simply need to rewrite `resp.http.Set-Cookie` using `regsub()`.

However, if multiple `Set-Cookie` headers are possible in a single response, previous solution is not valid. You could consider a similar approach, first merging all `Set-Cookie` headers in a single comma-delimited `Set-Cookie` header using `std.collect()`, and the rewriting the merged header using `regsuball()` to add the `HttpOnly` flag. However, merging `Set-Cookie` headers is a bad idea. Some browsers don't like merged headers and prefer that each `Set-Cookie` header is sent separately.

**Summary: there is nothing you can do in VCL to add the `HttpOnly` flag when multiple `Set-Cookie` headers are possible in a single response. That can only be implemented [using a VMOD](http://varnish-cache.org/vmods/). I'm not aware of any VMOD doing what you need, but it could be trivially implemented on your own.**